# Computing $\int_\alpha (\operatorname{Re} z)^2\,\mathrm dz$ and $\int_{\alpha}|\overline z^n||\mathrm dz|$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Can anyone help me with working out the following integrals:
$$\int_\alpha (\operatorname{Re} z)^2\,\mathrm dz ~~~\text{and}~~~ \int_\alpha|\overline z^n||\mathrm dz|$$
I tried to work out it with substituting the paramazetion $\alpha=e^{it}$ with $0\leq t\leq2\pi$ but it didn't give me the correct answer.

Comment: What's $\alpha$? Unit circle?

Comment: Yes, it is the unit circle.

Comment: For the second integral, I think you mean $\int_\alpha|f(z)||dz|$ right?

Comment: The computation is pretty lengthy, please be patient.

Comment: I'm going to assume $n\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: If $\alpha$ is the unit circle centered at $0$ then you have $|\overline z^n|= 1. \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

First we evaluate for $f(z)=(Re(z))^2$.

If $\alpha$ is the unit circle, then we choose the parameterization as the unit circle,

$$z=e^{it}=\cos{t} +i\sin{t},\ 0\leq t \leq 2\pi$$

Then, $$dz=ie^{it}\ dt=(-\sin{t}+i\cos{t})\ dt$$
and $$|dz|=\sqrt{\sin^2t+\cos^2t}\ dt=dt$$

Also, $$f(z)=(Re(z))^2 = \cos^2 t$$
and $$|f(z)|=|\cos^2 t|$$

So in particular,

$$\int_\alpha f(z)\ dz=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^2t(-\sin t+i\cos t)\ dt=0$$
and
$$\int_\alpha |f(z)|\ |dz|=\int_{0}^{2\pi}|\cos^2t|\ dt=\pi$$

Evaluate now for $f(z)=\overline z^n,\ n \in \mathbb{Z}$

I'll let you work out for the second example, giving you some hints on the way.

If $n=1$, we have that $$\int_\alpha \overline z^n\ dz =\int_\alpha \overline z\ dz=2\pi i$$
If $n \not=1$, we have that $$\int_\alpha \overline z^n\ dz =0$$